# Is this Volcanic or Impact winter management proposal right?

Tags: atmospheric-science, earth, geophysics

In case of a **volcanic winter** where a *VEI 8* volcano releases large amounts of *SO2* and *H2S* into the stratosphere making it react with *OH* and *H2O* to form sulfuric acid (*H2SO4*) wich would prohibit most of sunlight for reaching the surface for years, potentially causing a mass extinction, could we do something to remove those large quantities of sulphur aerosols?

I thought that, because *H2SO4* reacts with *NaCl* to form hydrogen chloride (*HCl*) and sodium bisulfate (*NaHSO4*) at room temperature like you [can see here](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=g0qqW9oeQbw) and [here](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=e_kZe73QC5o), we could perform a massive geoengineering project contrary to the **stratosphereic aerosol injection** by spreading sodium chloride in the atmosphere and avoiding the effects of a **volcanic winter** or an **impact winter** by replacing them with the products of that large-scale reaction.

Is my reasoning wrong? If it is, could you come up with another strategy?

[image]

Thanks for your time!!

Answer (score 2):

Sulfuric acid must be dry (concentrated) for the reaction with salt to produce HCl gas. If it is wet (dilute) there is essentially no reaction.

This is important because sulfuric acid is also extremely hygroscopic and will absorb water, diluting itself. [Sulfuric acid will dilute itself to 80% concentration even if the relative humidity is only 1%!](https://bio.groups.et.byu.net/Equilibrium_Humidity_of_Sulfuric_Solutions.phtml) The required dry conditions for this reaction would be very hard to achieve in the atmosphere.

Even if this reaction could be encouraged to proceed, you should also consider whether the products (sodium bisulfate and HCl) might have similar light-blocking effects to the reactants. In other words, by rearranging the atoms in this way, have you actually solved the problem, or just "rearranged the deck chairs on the Titanic"?